# XCode8-Archive not finished

Tags: swift3, xcode8

**Problem**: Using XCode 8 to archive project is not successful 
recently i migrated my Old iOS project created using XCode 7 with swift 2.2.

after migration i can install build on device directly but could not archive. while archiving i saw activity monitor which shows swift 100 % on cpu. the archive process not stopped after one hour. i received four type of warning from XCode 8 .

1. Deprecated
2. Swift Compiler Warning
3. Deprecations
4. Semantic Issue
5. Apple Mach-O Linker(ld) Warning

Is this supposed to be the problem for archiving ???
[image]

Comment: try making archive with Xcode 8.2 if you have support of swift 3.

Comment: yeah , XCode8.2 tried but it also hanging on Archive.

Comment: Can you show me a screen shot?

Comment: Does your project have Automatically manage signing?

Comment: yes. I tried to different account also. whatever account is signed in is not a problem for this.

Comment: just try to clear derived data and make one again!.

Comment: Finally find solution for this ,by changing OptimizationLevel in BuildSettings to Fast,Single-File Optimization[-O]. it solved the hand issue . anyway thanks for immediate support

Comment: alright. I am glad that your issue was resolved. your welcome anyways.